# how to provide authentication token to login api by alamofire4 and swift3

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, token, alamofire

all.

I can get authentication token by login. but I can authenticate on my server by swift and alamofire.

this is Postman. as you see, if i have token, i can be authenticated on myserver.
[image]

this is swift viewcontroller.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import KeychainAccess

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let authLoginUrl = "http://ec2-52-79-155-29.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/rest-auth/login/"
    let keychain = Keychain(service: "wanote")
    let projectUrl = "http://ec2-52-79-155-29.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8000/api/user/ryulstory"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let username = "username"
        let password = "1234!"

        self.doAuth(username: username, password: password)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func doAuth(username:String, password:String) {
        let params = ["username": username, "password": password]
        var authToken = Alamofire.request(self.authLoginUrl, method: .post, parameters: params)
        authToken.responseJSON { response in
            let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode ?? 0

            switch statusCode {
            case 200...299:
                let jsonData = JSON(response.result.value)
                if let token = jsonData["key"].string{
                    self.keychain["token"] = token
                    self.getProjects()
                }
            case 400...499:
                print("Server responded no")

            case 500...599:
                print("Server error")

            default:
                print("There was an error with your request")
            }

    }
}

    func getProjects(){
        if let token = self.keychain["token"] {
            if let Purl = URL(string: self.projectUrl){
                var mutableUrlRequest = URLRequest(url: Purl)
                mutableUrlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
                mutableUrlRequest.setValue("Token " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                var manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
                var getProjectsRequest = manager.request(mutableUrlRequest)
                    getProjectsRequest.responseJSON { response in
                        print(response.data)
                }

            }

        } else {
            print("no token")
        }


    }


}
```

I checked getting token by function doAuth. it is correctly operating.
function getprojects makes error status code 401. 
I think there are problem in function getprojects. but i can't find it.

could you help me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes to 401 because you are sending the request without the header authorization.

With Alamofire you can set the header Authorization like this.

```
    let url = "URL_LOGIN"
    //Get token logic
    let token = ""
    let headers = ["Authorization": "Token \(token)"]
    let params = ["user": "", "pass":""] //This goes in the body of the request
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            print(value)
        }

    }
```

With this you'll send the headers in the request to get what you want.

Comment: could you see me my answer it is below.

Comment: it is perfectly operating Thanks you. i had to change that " method: .post to method: .get"

Comment: @박형렬 Happy to help, set te answer as valid!

Answer (score 0):

I think this part have the header authorization.
is it wrong?

```
mutableUrlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
                mutableUrlRequest.setValue("Token " + token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                var manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
                var getProjectsRequest = manager.request(mutableUrlRequest)
```

Comment: It is ok, but Alamofire give you the chance to set it in the request, so it's not necessary to create a MutableUrlRequest. That's why I put it in my answer